# Stepwise verification code cleanup

Tags: java, function, module

Lets assume a stepwise code

```
stepWise () {
   Object a = getA ();
   Object b = getB (a);
   Object c = getC (b);
}
```

If for such a code I need to add verification, I need recommendation for cleanest way to do it.

```
stepWise () {
  Object a = getA();
  if ( a!= null ) {
     Object b = getB(a);
     if (b! = null) {
        Object c = getC(c);
     }
  }
}
```

Now only problem is more sequences if added ( getD(), getE() etc.) will create more mess.

1. Any clean solution ?
2. Or should i just validate parameters are non-null in respective functions?

Comment: Perhaps you should go with option 2.

Comment: Use any form of pipelining, the command pattern, etc. Each step represented by an instance of an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider as an alternative using the [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) design pattern to avoid having to perform all of these checks.

It's also not clear why you have:

```
getB(a)
```

as opposed to:

```
a.getB();
```

Originally I was thinking you could just do something like:

```
stepWise () {
  Object a = getA();
  Object b = getB();
  Object c = getC();

  checkNotNull(a);
  checkNotNull(b);
  checkNotNull(c);
  ...
```

but the way you've designed your classes, thats not possible.

Comment: class Tree {                                     findInoderSuccessor(int x) {                                       Node n = nodeForX(x); Node successorNode = inorder(n); return n.item };

Comment: uh, what is your comment in reference to?

Comment: It was not clear to you why i could not do a.getB(), in this case i cannot do node.getInorder();